# How can I optimize AWS Timestream queries to reduce costs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

I am using AWS Timestream to ingest data and also query data. Everything is working great. However, the AWS bill is strange. Right now most of the monthly bill ($251/$253) is from the queries.
Here's what AWS Cost Explorer shows:

price per GB scanned by Timestream queries - US West (Oregon)
Usage Quantity: 25,121.169 GB
Amount in USD: USD 251.21

So I am thinking maybe something is wrong with the way I'm querying data.

This is the query format I am using:
`select time, sensor1, sensor2, sensor3, sensor4, sensor5 from "table"."%s" where time >= '%s' and time <= '%s' and user = '%d' order by time`
`

Can anyone suggest a better query format that accomplishes the same goal? For example, would changing the "where time >= and time <=" to "time between %s and %s" be better? Or is that irrelevant? Do I just have too much data in the database?

Thanks in advance!

I tried viewing bill on AWS cost explorer but didn't get much information there

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the community! First, using "between" on the query shouldn't matter but it's, in my opinion, more readable (easier to understand). Second, the cost is associated with the bytes scanned so, if you have big dimensions and big measures, it will be expensive to query. If you want more detailed help, I would suggest providing some sample of the data and the schema of your table, so I can suggest improvements.

Comment: Thanks @EduardoEliasSaléh . 1) OK "between" wouldn't change anything, got it thanks!
2) How is "bytes scanned" defined? Is that the total size of the database? Is that size of database * number of queries?
3) I'll get back to you on sample data and schema... basically it's one table with ~10 columns with things like userID, timestamp, sensor data, etc

Comment: Bytes scanned means "bytes that were not outlined on an index". Let's say that your query is looking for a metric/measurement using several dimensions, the dimensions you use should help you diminish the amount of data you're scanning. I hope that clarifies a bit better the "scanned bytes" part.